# Is there any way to forward an HttpServletResponse as RequestParameter in feign proxies?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-cloud-feign

I have two microservices, one `api-gateway` and a `logging-server` which logs all important logs from all the microservices. I'm using feign proxy and spring-mvc to communicate in my microservices. so far I have the `LoggingController` in logging-server like so :

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/logging/")
public class LoggingController {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggingController.class);

    @PostMapping("/trafic")
    public void logRequest(
        HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response,
        @RequestBody String body
    )
    {
        // logging code here
    }
```

and my feign `LoggingProxy` in `api-gateway` :

```java
@FeignClient(name = "logging-server")
@RibbonClient(name = "logging-server")
@RequestMapping("/logging/")
public interface LoggingProxy {

    @PostMapping("/trafic")
    void logRequest(
        HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response,
        @RequestBody String body
    );

}
```

and my `LoggingFilter` which is a spring-security filter :

```java
@Component
@Order(0)
public class LoggingFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Autowired
    private LoggingProxy logging;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(
        HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response,
        FilterChain filterChain
    ) throws ServletException, IOException
    {

        if (logging == null) {
            WebApplicationContext webApp = WebApplicationContextUtils
                    .getWebApplicationContext(request.getServletContext());
            logging = webApp.getBean(LoggingProxy.class);
        }

        // this object extends `HttpServletResponseWrapper` and just stores the body content of the response
        HttpServletResponseCopier responseWrapper = new HttpServletResponseCopier(response);
        filterChain.doFilter(request, responseWrapper);

        // responseWrapper.getBody() gives the response body as a String
        logging.logRequest(request, responseWrapper, responseWrapper.getBody());

    }

}
```

but when I run this code I get a Spring error about saying my proxy has too many Body parameters:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException. Message: Error creating bean with name 'loggingFilter': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'logging'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.agenda.gateway.proxies.LoggingProxy': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method has too many Body parameters: public abstract void org.agenda.gateway.proxies.LoggingProxy.logRequest(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse,java.lang.String)
2019-11-09 08:53:41.536  INFO [agenda-gateway,,,] 14104 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2019-11-09 08:53:41.542  WARN [agenda-gateway,,,] 14104 --- [           main] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       : The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [spring.cloud.inetutils] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.base@13.0.1/java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.getHostByAddr(Native Method)
 java.base@13.0.1/java.net.InetAddress$PlatformNameService.getHostByAddr(InetAddress.java:936)
 java.base@13.0.1/java.net.InetAddress.getHostFromNameService(InetAddress.java:660)
 java.base@13.0.1/java.net.InetAddress.getHostName(InetAddress.java:603)
 java.base@13.0.1/java.net.InetAddress.getHostName(InetAddress.java:575)
 app//org.springframework.cloud.commons.util.InetUtils$$Lambda$233/0x0000000800d2e440.call(Unknown Source)
 java.base@13.0.1/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
 java.base@13.0.1/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
 java.base@13.0.1/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
 java.base@13.0.1/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
2019-11-09 08:53:41.543  WARN [agenda-gateway,,,] 14104 --- [           main] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       : The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [RxIoScheduler-1 (Evictor)] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.base@13.0.1/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
 java.base@13.0.1/java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:235)
 java.base@13.0.1/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2123)
 java.base@13.0.1/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1182)
 java.base@13.0.1/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:899)
 java.base@13.0.1/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1054)
 java.base@13.0.1/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1114)
 java.base@13.0.1/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
 java.base@13.0.1/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
2019-11-09 08:53:41.546  WARN [agenda-gateway,,,] 14104 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
2019-11-09 08:53:41.592  INFO [agenda-gateway,,,] 14104 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-11-09 08:53:41.608 ERROR [agenda-gateway,,,] 14104 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:156) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:544) ~[spring-context-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.agenda.gateway.AgendaGatewayApplication.main(AgendaGatewayApplication.java:16) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:126) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:88) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:438) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:191) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:180) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:153) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    ... 8 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'loggingFilter': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'logging'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.agenda.gateway.proxies.LoggingProxy': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method has too many Body parameters: public abstract void org.agenda.gateway.proxies.LoggingProxy.logRequest(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse,java.lang.String)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:639) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:116) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:397) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1429) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:207) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:211) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addAsRegistrationBean(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:174) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addAsRegistrationBean(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:169) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addAdaptableBeans(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:154) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.<init>(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:86) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.getServletContextInitializerBeans(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:253) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.selfInitialize(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:227) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter.onStartup(TomcatStarter.java:53) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5135) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:841) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:421) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:459) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:107) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    ... 13 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.agenda.gateway.proxies.LoggingProxy': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method has too many Body parameters: public abstract void org.agenda.gateway.proxies.LoggingProxy.logRequest(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse,java.lang.String)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:178) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:101) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1818) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1266) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:260) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.addCandidateEntry(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1510) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1467) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1250) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1207) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:636) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    ... 54 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method has too many Body parameters: public abstract void org.agenda.gateway.proxies.LoggingProxy.logRequest(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse,java.lang.String)
    at feign.Util.checkState(Util.java:130) ~[feign-core-10.4.0.jar:na]
    at feign.Contract$BaseContract.parseAndValidateMetadata(Contract.java:117) ~[feign-core-10.4.0.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.support.SpringMvcContract.parseAndValidateMetadata(SpringMvcContract.java:188) ~[spring-cloud-openfeign-core-2.2.0.RC1.jar:2.2.0.RC1]
    at feign.Contract$BaseContract.parseAndValidatateMetadata(Contract.java:66) ~[feign-core-10.4.0.jar:na]
    at feign.ReflectiveFeign$ParseHandlersByName.apply(ReflectiveFeign.java:154) ~[feign-core-10.4.0.jar:na]
    at feign.ReflectiveFeign.newInstance(ReflectiveFeign.java:52) ~[feign-core-10.4.0.jar:na]
    at feign.Feign$Builder.target(Feign.java:251) ~[feign-core-10.4.0.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.HystrixTargeter.target(HystrixTargeter.java:36) ~[spring-cloud-openfeign-core-2.2.0.RC1.jar:2.2.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignClientFactoryBean.loadBalance(FeignClientFactoryBean.java:242) ~[spring-cloud-openfeign-core-2.2.0.RC1.jar:2.2.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignClientFactoryBean.getTarget(FeignClientFactoryBean.java:271) ~[spring-cloud-openfeign-core-2.2.0.RC1.jar:2.2.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignClientFactoryBean.getObject(FeignClientFactoryBean.java:251) ~[spring-cloud-openfeign-core-2.2.0.RC1.jar:2.2.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:171) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    ... 65 common frames omitted
```

I've already tried wrapping the reques, response and body into an object and sending object as `@RequestBody` in controller but I had serialization errors.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: If you don't mind my question, is there a specific use-case for that? Using a log aggregator stack such as ELK is not an option?

Comment: I don’t know this but my goal is to have specific logs for the requests and responses so if the log aggregator can do it, i would be happy to learn more about that

Comment: There are a few open-source options to do what you need, you can start your search using ELK stack.

Comment: I read more about ELK which seems great in logs handling but I still can't log my requests since I can not forward them to my logging server. Thanks about ELK btw

Comment: You shouldn't need your logging server at all, the idea of using a log aggregator is to avoid what you're trying to do. Let's say you have 50 microservices and for each request you have to forward it to your logging server, it will eventually become a bottleneck. It's better if your microservice logs what needs to be logged and a tool such as ELK aggregates that for you.

Comment: Ok thank you so much for these answers, it perfectly fits my problem now.